# Match Function looping through variable string with offset corresponding value

Tags: excel, function, vba, match, worksheet

I am trying to cycle through names of customers on one sheet (sheet2), take the corresponding value in column J in sheet1 and then paste next to the customers on the original sheet.

This is my code:

```
For i = 0 To 9

Dim rowi As Long

rowi = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match((Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(5 + i, 4)), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B"), 0)
Crystali = Cells(rowi, 10)
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(5 + i, 7) = Crystali
Next i
```

Can someone help me fix it? I keep getting the error "Unable to get the Match property of Worksheetfunction class"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error generally means the value was not found. If you drop the `Worksheetfunction` part then you can test the return value with IsError() without a non-match causing an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I'm slightly confused - Couldn't you just use a vlookup or actual worksheet function to accomplish exactly this? Why use VBA???

Comment: This is part of a far larger vba project, the values change everyday and is in a seperately workbook. That's why I have chosen this match function. I am a beginner at vba and imagine my coding is very inefficient. 

If you have any suggestions or tips, I'd love to hear them.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

here short example how to use the **'Match()' function** without 'worksheet-function' part like Tim suggests. After the Match function was called just check the result with **'IsError()'**.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim row_index As Long
    Dim match_result As Variant
    Dim lookup_value As Variant
    Dim lookup_array As Variant

    Set lookup_array = Range("Sheet1!B:B")

    Const FIRST_ROW As Byte = 5
    Const LAST_ROW As Byte = 9

    For row_index = FIRST_ROW To LAST_ROW

        Set lookup_value = Range("Sheet2!D" & row_index)
        match_result = Application.Match(lookup_value, lookup_array, 0)

        If Not IsError(match_result) Then
            ' copy data only if Match function found something
            Range("Sheet2!G" & row_index) = Range("Sheet1!J" & match_result)
        End If

    Next row_index
End Sub
```